# How to remove duplicated array objects in PHP?

Tags: php

I have this code below which will get the array object.

```
// fetch all circuits
$circuits = $Tools->fetch_all_circuits();

// check locations
if($circuits!==false) {
    // all locations
    $all_locations = array ();
    // loop
    foreach ($circuits as $circuit) {
        // format points
        $locationA = $Tools->reformat_circuit_location ($circuit->device1, $circuit->location1);
        $locationB = $Tools->reformat_circuit_location ($circuit->device2, $circuit->location2);

        if($locationA['location']!="" && $locationB['location']!="") {
            $locA = $Tools->fetch_object ("locations", "id", $locationA['location']);
            $locB = $Tools->fetch_object ("locations", "id", $locationB['location']);
            // save to all_locations array
            if ($locA!==false && $locB!==false) {
                $all_locations[] = $locA;
                $all_locations[] = $locB;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump ($all_locations);
```

How can i get the unique object from this array?

i var_dump($all_locations), i have this array output (i deleted some object, to lessen the output).

```
array(28) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#51 (6) { ["id"]=> string(3) "950"
["name"]=> string(4) "5829" ["description"]=> string(4) "Null"
["address"]=> string(4) "Null" ["lat"]=> string(7) "21.5336"
["long"]=> string(7) "39.2178" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#52 (6) {
["id"]=> string(3) "987" ["name"]=> string(4) "5765" ["description"]=>
string(4) "Null" ["address"]=> string(4) "Null" ["lat"]=> string(7)
"21.5439" ["long"]=> string(7) "39.2243" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#54
(6) { ["id"]=> string(4) "1016" ["name"]=> string(4) "2228"
["description"]=> string(4) "Null" ["address"]=> string(4) "Null"
["lat"]=> string(7) "21.5447" ["long"]=> string(7) "39.2301" } [27]=>
object(stdClass)#84 (6) { ["id"]=> string(4) "2536" ["name"]=>
string(4) "2389" ["description"]=> string(4) "Null" ["address"]=>
string(4) "Null" ["lat"]=> string(6) "21.495" ["long"]=> string(6)
"39.966" } }
```

Comment: `array_unique()`

Comment: Can you provide an example  of your array? Just var_dump it and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**array_unique()** will help you in that. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

array_unique() sorts the values treated as a string at first, then will keep the first key encountered for every value, and ignore all following keys. It does not mean that the key of the first related value from the unsorted array will be kept.

Comment: you can upvote is the solution has helped you.@Jovanni